# Ruby Many HTTP Requests

Tags: ruby, net-http

In the Ruby docs for [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) it says

> The Net::HTTP methods in the following section do not persist
>   connections. They are not recommended if you are performing many HTTP
>   requests.

But then the docs don't say anything about what you should use if you DO want to make a lot of HTTP requests. What should be used?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. Are you making many sequential requests to a single host? Many requests to many different hosts? Many concurrent requests to a single host?

Comment: @meagar Many concurrent requests to different hosts

Comment: Then look into something like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus).

Comment: @meagar Typhoeus does what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Actually the docs DO say how you can reuse connection for multiple requests:

> If you wish to re-use a connection across multiple HTTP requests
>   without automatically closing it you can use ::new instead of ::start.
>   request will automatically open a connection to the server if one is
>   not currently open. You can manually close the connection with finish.

You can find this in this section: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-How+to+use+Net-3A-3AHTTP

Comment: I'm not looking to re-use a connection. I'm looking for concurrent connections to different hosts.